# Fourier series and coefficients c1

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in C_{st}$ be a function defined as: 
$$f(x) = e^{i\left|x\right|} \ \text{for  $x\in]-\pi,\pi[$}$$

For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ let $c_n$ define the $n^{th}$ Fourier Coefficient for $f$ with respect to the usual orthonormal system $\text{{${e_n |n\in\mathbb{Z}}$}}$

Show that $c_0 = \frac{2i}{\pi}$ og $c_1 = \frac{1}{2}$

---

I have worked with complex Fourier Series where the $c_n$ coefficient is given by: $$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}\mathrm{d}x.$$

Based on this, I believe I have found $c_0$

$$c_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i|x|}e^{-i0x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0}e^{i(-x)}\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{ix}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(i\left[e^{i(-x)} \right]_{-\pi}^0 +i \left[e^{ix} \right]_{0}^{\pi}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(i\cdot(1+1 \right)+i(1+1)) =\frac{4i}{2\pi}=\frac{2i}{\pi}$$

However, I am not sure how to calculate $c_1$, I hope someone can show it.

Comment: Why not just do the same kind of thing you already did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just work it out, like $c_0$.

> $$c_1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0}e^{i(-x)}e^{-ix}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{ix}e^{-ix}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\left(\frac{e^{-i2x}}{-2i}\right)^{0}_{\pi}+\left(\pi\right)\right]=\frac{1}{2} $$ as desired.

Comment: I am just messing it up, but this is what I have for $c_1$ 
$$c_1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0}e^{i(-x)}e^{-ix}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{ix}e^{-ix}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0}e^{-2ix}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{ix}e^{-ix}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(-2i[e^{-2ix}]^{0}_{-\pi}+ \left[ 1 \right]_0^{\pi}\right)$$ 
I am pretty sure I made a wrong calculation here, also for the calculation for $c_0$ Shouldn't I have $-i \cdot (1+1)$?

Comment: Because $$\int e^{\alpha x}dx=\frac{e^{\alpha x}}{\alpha}+C$$.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course then I get the right thing, thanks!

Comment: But is my calculation for $c_0$ correct, more specifically $\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(i\left[e^{i(-x)} \right]_{-\pi}^0 +i \left[e^{ix} \right]_{0}^{\pi}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(i\cdot(1+1 \right)+i(1+1))$ ?

Comment: It's $\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\left[\frac{e^{i(-x)}}{-i} \right]_{-\pi}^0 + \left[\frac{e^{ix}}{i} \right]_{0}^{\pi}\right)$.